# Rails: form_for security hole?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, form-for

I have a user model with :name and :is_admin attributes. You should not change is_admin value. If you write a form in which any user may edit their name:

```
<%= form_for @user %>
    <%= f.label :given_name %>  
    <%= f.text_field :given_name %>
    <%= f.submit "Update"  %>
<% end %>
```

Are you opening up a security hole?

Kind regards,

Answer (score 5):

**No.**

This is because parameters are protected when they come into the controller by the strong parameters feature within Rails. In controllers now you define a create action like this:

```
def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  ...
end
```

That `user_params` method looks like this:

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name)
end
```

This code will permit the name parameter from the user parameters and outright reject everything else.

This is talked about [in this section of the Getting Started guide.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#saving-data-in-the-controller)